# Is there any limit on amount in payfort payment gateway?

Tags: php, laravel, payfort

Is there any limit on amount for test cards (in testing phase) in **payfort payment gateway**?

Comment: maybe..........

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented payfort in my project and talked to payfort's support and integration group.

They have told me that **Payfort** has no limit on amount in test phase. But keep in mind you have to send amount in **int** datatype, **float** will not accepted.